# The stack around variable was corrupted calling a driver

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

I am trying to get the pids of all the processes that are getting executed on the computer using a kernel mode driver. But when requesting the driver, I get a error.

here is the function that fails, the problematic variable is "Id"

```
    DWORD GetTargetPid()
{
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    DWORD Id = 0;
    DWORD Bytes = 0;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_GET_ID_REQUEST, &Id, sizeof(Id),
        &Id, sizeof(Id), &Bytes, NULL))
        return Id;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and here is the code handling the request in the driver :

```
else if (ControlCode == IO_GET_ID_REQUEST)
{
    PULONG OutPut = (PULONG)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    *OutPut = id;

    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "id get %#010x", id);
    Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    BytesIO = sizeof(OutPut);
}
...
// Complete the request
Irp->IoStatus.Status = Status;
Irp->IoStatus.Information = BytesIO;
IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

return Status;
```

I just don't understand why I have this problem, as I use DWORD in each part of the code.

Comment: `sizeof(OutPut)` -- This gives you the sizeof() a pointer.  Is this what you really intended?

Comment: Also, the excessive usage of `sizeof` -- you do know that `sizeof()` is a *compile-time* value?  If you're intent is to get sizes of runtime allocated buffers, `sizeof()` will not work.

Comment: Being a compile time value isn't really a big problem, as I use integers, no dynamically allocated buffers.
But that sizeof(Output) might be the problem.

Comment: Well if your intent with the `sizeof()` was to get the size of that buffer, unless that buffer is a static array that has its size known at compile-time, then that's an issue.  You can't use `sizeof()` in that case.

Comment: at first you not check input/output buffer lengths. if you want output `ULONG`  - simply set `sizeof (ULONG)`. also if you process all ioctl synchronous and not call other drivers - much more better implement `FastIoDeviceControl` instead `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL` handler